# How do I separate the multiple arrays in my php variable?

Tags: php, arrays

The variable is a result of this foreach loop but when I print it I would like just one array not multiple arrays.

Foreach Loop Code:

```
foreach ($finalpagesID as $value) {
    $IDjsonPage = json_decode(
        file_get_contents($pageURL.$value['id']), TRUE
    );      
    $IDvar = array(
        'name' => $IDjsonPage["name"],
        'X'    => $IDjsonPage["X"],
        'Y'    => $IDjsonPage["Y"],
        'Z'    => $IDjsonPage["Z"]
    );

    print_r ($IDvar);
};
```

Results:

```
Array ( [name] => 1905 Restaurant [X] => 5869 [Y] => 1299 [Z] => 43 )
Array ( [name] => 15 Ria [X] => 0 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 )
Array ( [name] => 18th Amendment LLC [X] => 3384 [Y] => 111 [Z] => 1 )
Array ( [name] => 1920dc [X] => 0 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 )
Array ( [name] => 19th St Pub [X] => 1 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 )
Array ( [name] => 2 Birds 1 Stone [X] => 1884 [Y] => 603 [Z] => 37 )
Array ( [name] => Bar 201 [X] => 30 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 )
Array ( [name] => 51st State Tavern [X] => 3944 [Y] => 365 [Z] => 20 )
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: i want something like this that I can the convert to JSON. Array ( [1]([name] => 1905 Restaurant [X] => 5869 [Y] => 1299 [Z] => 43 ) [2] [[name] => 15 Ria [X] => 0 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 ) [3]([name] => 18th Amendment LLC [X] => 3384 [Y] => 111 [Z] => 1 )

Comment: I edited your question a bit, breaking up long lines into separate lines. This will make it easier for people to read your code and help you getting an answer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you actually *want* multiple arrays. Into one array. Something like:

```
$IDvar = array();
foreach ($finalpagesID as $value) {

    $IDjsonPage = json_decode(file_get_contents($pageURL.$value['id']),TRUE);

    $IDvar[] = array('name'=>$IDjsonPage["name"],'X'=>$IDjsonPage["X"],'Y'=>$IDjsonPage["Y"],'Z'=>$IDjsonPage["Z"]);

}
print_r ($IDvar);
```

Or, maybe:

```
$IDvar = array();
foreach ($finalpagesID as $value) {

    $IDjsonPage = json_decode(file_get_contents($pageURL.$value['id']),TRUE);

    $IDvar[$IDjsonPage["name"]] = array('X'=>$IDjsonPage["X"],'Y'=>$IDjsonPage["Y"],'Z'=>$IDjsonPage["Z"]);

}
print_r ($IDvar);
```

Or, maybe:

```
$IDvar = array();
foreach ($finalpagesID as $value) {

    $IDjsonPage = json_decode(file_get_contents($pageURL.$value['id']),TRUE);

    $IDvar[$IDjsonPage["X"]][$IDjsonPage["Y"]][$IDjsonPage["Z"]] = $IDjsonPage["name"];

}
print_r ($IDvar);
```

(Judging for your comment, the first proposed solution would be the one you want to go with, although the index of the first element would be 0, not 1 because PHP arrays use [zero based numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#Usage_in_programming_languages))

Comment: *want multiple arrays. Into one array* It's called multidimensional array

Comment: (Although being a MSc. I like to reserve that nomenclature for |N<->|N arrays to avoid conflict with the concept of rank, dimension or dimensionality in linear algebra, which may come up as a little bit pedant but it actually avoids a lot of confusion in the lab when working with feature selection/extraction in the context of dimensionality reduction for recommender system algorithms and applied discrete linear regression algorithms in general)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I'm still getting a similary output though  Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 1905 Restaurant [X] => 5869 [Y] => 1299 [Z] => 43 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 15 Ria [X] => 0 [Y] => 0 [Z] => 0 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 18th Amendment LLC [X] => 3384 [Y] => 111 [Z] => 1 ) )

Answer (score 0):

array_push() will create a multidimentional array with index for each "push"

```
$IDvar = array();

foreach ($finalpagesID as $value)
{
    $IDjsonPage = json_decode(file_get_contents($pageURL.$value['id']),TRUE);       
    array_push($IDvar, array('name'=>$IDjsonPage["name"],'X'=>$IDjsonPage["X"],'Y'=>$IDjsonPage["Y"],'Z'=>$IDjsonPage["Z"]));
};
print_r ($IDvar);
```

Comment: still not working unfortunately. It still separates each iteration in the loop into a separate array.